# How to delete specific row in the gridview when item is binded from session

Tags: asp.net, gridview, radgrid, delete-row

I have grid where i am binding items from session variable , where their around 5 similar items in the grid, i have to delete a specific selected row , on what basis i can delete the selected item, when all the columns have similar items and  feilds?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you said you want to delete the selected row, for this you can use `RowIndex` to delete the selected row, `GridView` has a method `DeleteRow` which takes an index of row as a parameter.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, What if i am selecting multiple rows and obtain the row index of all the selected items, how should i change my codebehindlogic?

Answer (score 0):

If the items in the session variable have a Property used for identification that it is very easy.
Let's say that property name is UniqueId

When Binding the datasource to the gridview set before binding

```
DatKeyNames="UniqueId"
```

Then when you want to delete a row just get the UniqueId value from DataKeys

```
GridView1.DataKeys[DeleteRowIndex].Value
```

Where DeleteRowIndex is the index of the row being deleted from the grid view